Assisted inject for factory method
I have a factory method:
 public static MyDataService myDataService(DataFetcher dataFetcher, Config config)

I would like to crate an assisted factory out of it
@AssistedFactory
public interface MyDataServiceFactory {
  MyDataService create(Config config);
}

Is it possible? If not are there viable workarounds (my goal is to reduce boilerplate)

https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/4448
